# Geometric multiplicity vs degree of degeneracy of energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix  of order $n$. Given a fixed eigenvalue $\lambda$, we call **geometric multiplicty** the dimension of the associated eigenspace
$$g_{\lambda} = \dim(v\in\mathbb{K}^n : Av= \lambda v)$$

In quantum mechanics, we say an energy level is degenerate if it corresponds to two or more different measurable states of a quantum system. The **degree of degeneracy** is the number of different state corresponding to that energy level.

Are these two concept related? Knowing the Hamiltonian of a quantum system is essentially a linear operator and energy levels its eigenvalues, I guess so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same: the degeneracy of an energy value $E$ is the number of different states that share this same value, so it's the dimension of the eigenspace related to this particular value of $E$ (seen as an eigenvalue of the hamiltonian).

In my old math lessons, we didn't use the term "geometric multiplicity" and simply called "degree of degeneracy" the dimension of an eigenspace, so its use in physics isn't suprising.

Comment: Thanks,I think my linear algebra textbooks uses the term "geometric multiplicity" to stress the difference from "algebraic multiplicity".

Comment: You should be aware that this holds e.g. for Hermitean matrices. In more general cases, e.g. if an eigenvalue is twice degenerate one cannot find 2 eigenvectors with the same energy. In other words, in the general case, a matrix may not be diagonalizable.

Comment: I admit that this sort of result rings a bell but is a bit far in my memory. Thanks, I’ll clean up the dust. ;)